# React.js dynamically injecting html from database (sql) into component not applying css styles?

Tags: mysql, laravel, reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently injecting a html string from mysql via http and then displaying it in a component. It's kind of strange but my styling does not get applied to my dynamically injected html. However a few classes do from my other css library. But my bulma.css library styling does not seem to be applied.

I'm currently using, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}`

The html is being rendered in the browser successfully.

Here are my relevant files

**My React Component file**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPost } from '../actions/index';

class Article extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchPost();
    }

    createMarkup() {
        return {__html: this.props.post};
    }

    renderPosts(){

        if(!this.props.post){
            return(
                <img src="/app/img/loading.svg" alt=""/>
            )
        }

        if(this.props.post){
            return(
                  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} />
            )
        }

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div >{this.renderPosts()}</div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        post: state.posts.post
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost })(Article);
```

**My Index HTML file (blade file using laravel )**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/css/bulma-0.4.1/css/bulma.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/css/prism.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/css/app-style.css?{{str_random(40)}}">
        <title>Development Gems!</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="root">
    </div>

    <script src="/app/js/plugins/prism.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/js/app.bundle.js?{{str_random(40)}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My html string**

```html
 $data = '<div className="container padded-top-di-20">
                <div className="columns">
                    <div className="column">
                        <p className="title is-1 has-text-centered">How to install Laravel 5 with Xampp (Windows)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p className="title is-3">
                    Requirements
                </p>

               <div className="content">
                   <ul>
                       <li>Donec blandit a lorem id convallis.</li>
                       <li>Cras gravida arcu at diam gravida gravida.</li>
                       <li>Integer in volutpat libero.</li>
                       <li>Donec a diam tellus.</li>
                       <li>Aenean nec tortor orci.</li>
                       <li>Quisque aliquam cursus urna, non bibendum massa viverra eget.</li>
                       <li>Vivamus maximus ultricies pulvinar.</li>
                   </ul>
               </div>

                <p className="title is-3">
                    Install Xampp
                </p>

                <p>
                    First of all, we need Xampp, so we can download it from the official page:
                </p>

                <a href="https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html">Download Xampp</a>

                <p className="title is-3">
                    Composer
                </p>

                <p>
                    After you\'ve downloaded and installed Xampp, we need to install Composer.
                </p>

                <p>
                    Composer is a PHP package manager that is integrated with Laravel Framework. In Windows we can install it easy going to the official page and download the installer.
                </p>

                <div className="columns">
                    <div className="column">
                        <pre className="command-line language-bash" data-user="Thatguyjono94" data-host="localhost"><code className="language-bash">{`cd \/usr\/local\/etc`}</code></pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="columns">
                    <div className="column">
                        <pre className="command-line language-bash" data-user="Thatguyjono94" data-host="localhost"><code className="language-bash">{`cd \/usr\/local\/etc`}</code></pre>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="columns">
                    <div className="column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
                        <figure className="image is-128x128 margin-auto-di">
                            <img src="/app/img/profiles/avatar_icon-1.png" />
                        </figure>

                        <p className="title is-2 is-spaced has-text-centered">@Thatguyjono94</p>
                        <p className="subtitle is-4 has-text-centered">I\'m a DOPE AF web developer that focuses on building disruptive, fast moving and kick ass web applications.</p>

                        <div className="has-text-centered">
                            <span className="icon is-medium">
                              <i className="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span className="icon is-medium">
                              <i className="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span className="icon is-medium">
                              <i className="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dangerouslySetInnerHTML expects an HTML string. The string you are providing is formatted as a JSX string because it contains `className` instead of `class`. To fix it, convert each instance of `className` to `class`.

Comment: Thanks, the css coming from my bulma.css stylesheet is working but I think only parts of my prism.js and prism.css styling is working because it does not display how it should look. I tested that specific code in my index html file, the code looks like this `<pre class="command-line language-bash" data-user="Thatguyjono94" data-host="localhost"><code class="language-bash">cd /usr/local/etc</code></pre>` . And it looks completely different to the injected version in the react component. Strange? Should i try another plugin or there something i am missing? Thanks!

Comment: any chance you would know about this?